# Bootstrap3: Fix the row height

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Is it a good practice to have a fixed row height?
I am trying to use `help-block` class to show the error message dynamically but when I show the message it changes the complete grid layout.
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/himanshuy/HgAVP/1/)
That's how grid appears with no `help-block` message.
[image]

When I click on submit it checks if required fields are empty. If the are then this is how it appears.
[image]

Problem is that error messages are added dynamically which changes the height of row dynamically. How can I fix that?

Comment: Personally, I don't really see a problem with this (but I'm not a designer and have very poor aesthetic sense). On the the other hand, fixed row height might solve the problem but it will look too spaced out when there are no errors.

Comment: It is a big form and it does look bad with these error messages.

Comment: place your html output firstr

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a good practice to have a fixed row height?

yes it is.

one way of fixing the row height is to add the following css code to that specific page to over load the base bootstrap.css

```
<style>
    .row{ height:50px;}/* change it to the resulting height after the dynamic change*/
</style>
```

its not recommended to change the base file.

if you have other ro's that might change get affected by this change.
I'd recommend adding an extra class to those rows

```
<style>
    .fixed-row{ height:50px;}
</style>

<div class="row fixed-row"><!-- your fields --></div>
```

Comment: This would not be fixed height.

Comment: _the idea correct me if I'm wrong._ is to place a value equal to the resulting height to avoid the change.

Comment: You are correct, but only problem will appear in IE. Sorry I supposed to be in table his fiddle showing in div that will be perfect in any browser.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you show those messages by the text fields anyways? You already have the red * by each required field. Just add the error message all the way at the top (and make sure the page gets scrolled up to the error), or at the bottom, by the button they click.

And since you are using bootstrap, you may add a `.has-error` to the input fields that have the error. That would solve all your problems.

Fiddle example with Date of Birth having `.has-error`. http://jsfiddle.net/HgAVP/2/

Had to fix some of your classes to be fully Bootstrap compatible, though.

Comment: IMHO that will be bad user experience. In a big form user won't know which field need to be fixed.

Comment: I dont see how highlighting the fields in red is any different than adding a text message by those fields. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Added a fiddle with a `.has-error` on field Date of Birth to show an example... I dont see how that is bad user experience. http://jsfiddle.net/HgAVP/2/ Edit: I did have to fix some of his code though...